# Asymptotic Cone of Product Sets

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-analysis, economics, convex-cone

We denote the asymptotic cone of a set $S$ by $A(S)$: given $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a natural number $k$, let $\Gamma(S^k)$ be the smallest closed cone at $0$ containing $S^k=\{x\in S: ||x||\ge k\}$. The asymptotic cone of $S$ is $A(S)=\bigcap_{k\ge 0} \Gamma(S^k)$. Intuitively, $A(S)$ contains (the closure of) all directions $S$ contains at infinity.

For two non-empty sets $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n, T\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, it is claimed that
$A(S\times T)\subset A(S)\times A(T)$.

Question 1: How to prove it?

Question 2: Is there an example such that $A(S\times T)\neq A(S)\times A(T)$?

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: In this situation, the context will not help much. This is a claim in Section 1.9 of this monograph: https://cowles.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/pub/mon/m17-all.pdf

Comment: Context is important in every question. This question is no exception.

Comment: @wxydx00 That's already helpful context. What would make this question better would be information like, e.g. which page is the claim made on, what is the definition of the asymptotic cone (in the text), and what other information about the asymptotic cone do you know? While all this information is available to people who read through the pdf, writing it out will make this question more accessible, and thus more likely to be answered and upvoted,

Comment: Hi Theo: Thank you for your comment. I have written out the definition of the asymptotic cone.

Comment: @bobeyt6 That is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lemma:** $x \in A(S)$ if and only if there exists a sequence $s_k \in S$ and $\lambda_k \in [0, \infty)$, converging to $0$, such that $x = \lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda_k s_k$.

*Proof.* Suppose $x \in A(S)$. Then $x \in \Gamma(S^k)$ for all $k \ge 0$. Choose $x_k$ in $\Bbb{R}^+S_k$, the (not necessarily closed, not necessarily convex) conical hull of $S_k$, such that $\|x - x_k\| \le 1/k$. We know that $x_k$ must take the form $\lambda_k s_k$ for some $\lambda_k \ge 0$ and $s_k \in S^k$.

If $\operatorname*{limsup}_k\lambda_k > 0$, then a subsequence $\lambda_{k_l}$ converges to some $\lambda > 0$. We then have,
$$\|x_{k_l}\| = \lambda_{k_l} \|s_{k_l}\| \ge \frac{\lambda}{2}\|s_{k_l}\| \ge \frac{\lambda}{2}k_l \ge \frac{\lambda l}{2},$$
for sufficiently large $l$, so $\|x_{k_l}\|$ diverges to $\infty$. This contradicts $x_k \to x$ as $k \to \infty$.

Thus, $\operatorname*{limsup}_k\lambda_k = 0$. The limit inferior must be at least $0$, hence $\lim_k \lambda = 0$.

Conversely, suppose $s_k \in S$ and $\lambda_k$ are as in the lemma's statement. If any subsequence $s_{k_l}$ of $s_k$ is bounded by $M \ge 0$, then $\|\lambda_{k_l} s_{k_l}\| \le \lambda_{k_l} M \to 0$. But, at the same time, $\|\lambda_{k_l} s_{k_l}\| \to \|x\|$, hence $x = 0 \in A(S)$.

Otherwise, $\|s_k\| \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$. We can therefore take a subsequence $s_{k_m}$ such that $s_{k_m} \in S^m$, and so $\lambda_{k_m} s_{k_m} \in \Gamma(S^m)$, for all $m \in \Bbb{N}$. Then,
$$d(x, \Gamma(S^m)) = d(x, \Gamma(S^m)) - d(\lambda_{k_m}s_{k_m}, \Gamma(S^m)) \le \|x - \lambda_{k_m}s_{k_m}\| \to 0$$
as $m \to \infty$. But, since the $\Gamma(S^m)$ sets nest descendingly, we know that $d(x, \Gamma(S^m))$ is a montone increasing function, converging to $0$, consisting of non-negative entries. Thus, the only possibility is that $d(x, \Gamma(S^m)) = 0$, i.e. $x$ belongs to the closure of $\Gamma(S^m)$ (which is $\Gamma(S^m)$). That is, $x \in A(S)$.

---

With that lemma, the question is straightforward. If $(v, w) \in A(S \times T)$, then there exists some $\lambda_k \ge 0$, converging to $0$, and a sequence $(s_k, t_k) \in S \times T$ such that $(v, w) = \lim_{k \to \infty} (\lambda_k s_k, \lambda_k t_k)$. This, of course, translates to $v = \lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda_k s_k$ and $w = \lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda_k t_k$, which implies, by the lemma, that $(v, w) \in A(S) \times A(T)$.

---

To see why $A(S) \times A(T)$ need not be a subset of $A(S \times T)$, consider the following subset of $\Bbb{R}$:
$$S = T = \{2^n : n \in \Bbb{N}\}$$
Note that $A(S) = A(T) = [0, \infty)$, as the set consists of non-negative numbers and is unbounded above.

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $(1, 3) \in A(S \times T)$. Then there exists some sequence $(2^{n_k}, 2^{m_k}) \in S \times T$ and $\lambda_k \to 0$ such that $(1, 3) = \lim_k \lambda_k(2^{n_k}, 2^{m_k})$. The quotient of these two limits reveals:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2^{m_k - n_k} = 3.$$
But, $2^{m_k - n_k}$ takes values from the set $\{\ldots, 1/2, 1, 2, 4, \ldots\}$, and every possible value of $2^{m_k - n_k}$ is at least distance $1$ from $3$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First, $(v,w)$ may not be in $(S\times T)^k$. Indeed, $(v,w)$ may not be in $S\times T$ - the asymptotic cone may not be contained in the set: consider the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: xy=1,x,y\ge 0\}$. Its asymptotic cone is $\{(x,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x\ge 0\}\cup \{(0,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\ge 0\}$. For probably the same reason, I could not follow your example. I could understand the 45-degree line is not in $S\times T$, but I could not follow that the 45 degree line is not in $A(S\times T)$.

Comment: The first was my bad. I meant $(v, w)$ was contained in the cone generated by $(S \times T)^k$. I just tripped up on the notation. I think the rest of the proof should be fine. As for the next question, if the line were contained in $A(S \times T)$, then once again for any $k \ge 0$, we could write $(x, x) = \lambda_k(s_k, t_k)$, where $s_k^2 + t_k^2 \ge k^2$ and $s_k$ is rational, while $t_k$ is not. But then, assuming $x \neq 0$ (might as well), we see that $\lambda_k s_k = x = \lambda_k t_k$, and $\lambda_k \neq 0$. Thus, $s_k = t_k$, which contradicts exactly one being rational.

Comment: Thank you for your update. This updated proof still has some delicate problem (I comment by assuming you wrote $(v,w)=\lambda_k (s_k,t_k)$.): Note $\Gamma(S^k)$ is the smallest closed cone containing $S^k$, so for $v\in \Gamma(S^k)$, there may not be a $\lambda\ge 0$ such that $v=\lambda s$ for some $s\in S^k$. One example would be the $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y/x\in (-1,1), y>0\}\cup \{0\}$. In this case, $\Gamma(S^k)=cl(S)$. Take $(v,w)=(1,1)\in \Gamma(S^k)$.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's a point. That'll affect the other proof too. I'll have a think about it.

Comment: @wxydx00 OK, I've fixed it. I think.

Comment: Thank you. Now I think the proof is correct. (There are some typos but, personally, I prefer the answer to be left as it.)